# Hibernate Master-SubDetails Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'd like to explore Hibernate and used it in my project instead of JDBC.
My table design is highly normalized.

Suppose, I have this use case: Each insurance applied by a customer has one associated rateplan.  Usually, in RDBMS this is implemented using two tables like below.

```
Table Insurance:
    id long;
    accountHolder varchar;
    ratePlanId int;  -->Rate Plan Id is Foreign Key to the RatePlanTable

Table RatePlan:
    ratePlanId int;
    ratePlanDesc varchar;
    discountRate double;
```

Now, my question is..does this qualify as a onetomany relationship?

Most of the examples that I am seeing on the net regarding onetomany, involves some sort of collections (e.g An Order has a list of products). And when represented in class is translated below, which I think is really a one to many case?

```
public class Order{
    private List products;
}
```

But how about my case?  I don't think that it is a onetomany or I am just mislead by the examples?

How can I do a hbm mapping for my two classes?  In my case, I would create two class to represent the two tables, but I am not sure how the hbm.xml would look like for the two class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a one to many relationship, in that one rate plan is associated with many insurance policies.  In entity traversal, when you would go from the Policy, you would get one Plan object, and conversely, from a Plan object, you would get a list of Policy objects.

Comment: If thats the case then, in my Insurance.hbm.xml.. how would I represent the ratePlanId?  Will it be a set or a list or any other collection?  Can you please show me a sample hbm.mapping in this case? Thanks for responding

Comment: The Hibernate docs have some very clear examples (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association).  Check out sections 2.2.5.3.1.1., which is a corollary to your case - one Troop has a Set of Soldiers.

Comment: Hi, thats exactly where I am having some confusion..in the case on that link.. A troop really has a set of soldiers so it is logical to have a Set/List/Collection in your Troop Class.  But in my case, I have a Set of rate plan even though I can only have one?  Sorry, I am just confused but I am learning given your lead.  Thanks

Comment: No, you would have a set of Insurance in your RatePlan class, and a RatePlan in your Insurance class (many-to-one).